# Calling an SSRS Mobile Report in ASp.net web application

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2016

I have an application and I would like the default screen to be an SQL Mobile Report that I have built. I can see the report when I navigate to it and it looks fine but when I try to open it in an iFrame I get the following message

> This content cannot be displayed in a frame. To help protect the
>   security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of
>   this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.

How can I call my SSRS Mobile Report from my web application.  There  are no parameters to pass so its just a straight call.  Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I tried it in google chrome with no effect., I also made the changes indicated.  Is there anotherway to display the report either than through iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solutions:

1- Turn on compatibility view in your browser. For IE10: https://www.k-state.edu/its/helpdesk/ie10-enable-compatibility-mode.html

2- Turn off XSS filter: Please click `start`, type `inetcpl.cpl` and press `Enter`. Then select the `security` tab and click `Internet`. Go to `Custom Level`, at the bottom click `Disable` under `Enable XSS Filter` then click `OK`.

3-  Reset IE browser by going `Tools > Internet Options > Advanced Tab` and pressing `Reset` and reboot your browser.

4- In your browser: Tools > Internet options -> Privacy -> Click Advanced button
In `Advanced Privacy Settings` window, tick `Override automatic cookie handling` and press OK. Restart your browser.

5- Try another web browser :)

References:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2f95e434-7b30-4401-925e-0739b6227082/ie-8-frame-issue-this-content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame?forum=netfxjscript

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_7/this-content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame/a24b93c8-006c-4280-ba1f-01053665e22f

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows8_1/this-content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame/c2bfbee1-c253-4836-8423-b58cc58cb9ed?auth=1